# Imagenes - Base de Datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, img

Buenas tardes comunidad!!

Estoy teniendo problema con un código. Resulta que tengo un sistema con usuarios en el cual van a tener foto de perfil. Ya tengo la funcionalidad de cargar esa foto de perfil y enviarla a la base. Tengo la columna img_dato que es de tipo byte, y la columna img_tipo de varchar.

Ahora quiero traerme esa imagen de la base para visualizarla en la WEB.

Dos consultas:

1- Que respuesta debo esperar cuando consulto a la base de datos sobre x usuario y no tiene foto de perfil? Mi idea es para que cuando no tiene foto de perfil cargada, ponerle una imagen generica.

2- Por lo que vi para traerme un dato de tipo byte debo hacer una consulta ExecuteQueryByte. En paralelo hice otra consulta para trerme otros datos del usuario de la siguiente manera

```
$usuario->perfil = $this->admusuario->getPerfil($login);
```

Quisiera meter en $usuario->perfil el dato de la consulta querybyte, deberia tan solo poner:

```
$usuario->perfil->imagen_dato = resultado de la consulta querybyte?
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, en vez de responder lo que realmente estás preguntando, te voy a aconsejar guardar las imágenes como archivos, en vez de hacerlo en la base de datos.

Comment: Siguiendo creo la misma línea que @JoséCarlosPHP , después de guardar la imagen del usuario en una carpeta, guarda la URL de cada imagen en tu base. Cuando hagas la llamada la base te mandará  la URL que después podrás imprimir en un img tag.